# Take a screenshot in flex4

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I am building a widow AIR application. My application is transparent . I need to take a screenshot of my screen .Please help me in this

Answer (score 0):

AIR cant do it directly; but it can be done by creating an Air Native Extension (ANE) to talk to the OS and grab the bitmap data.

Or you could try Native Process (not sure it ifs still part of AIR now that we have ANEs). Heres a tutorial on using Native Process to take a screenshot: http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=125